# How best to deal with growing polymorphic interfaces?

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, polymorphism

Consider the following scenario in an object-oriented environment. Sample code is in C++, but it could be any OO language.

A software must control an external device, say a TV. From the start you know the software will need to handle different kind of TVs, so you go for an interface (pure abstract) to define the structure of the TVs and how they can be used:

```
class TelevisionInterface
{
public:
  virtual void TurnOn() = 0;
  virtual void TurnOff() = 0;
  virtual void SetVolume(int volume) = 0;
}
```

And then you start working on your first TV implementations, which inherit from TelevisionInterface:

```
class TelevisionSamsung123 : public TelevisionInterface
{
public:
  virtual void TurnOn() override { ... }
  virtual void TurnOff() override { ... }
  virtual void SetVolume(int volume) override { ... }
}

class TelevisionLg456 : public TelevisionInterface
{
public:
  virtual void TurnOn() override { ... }
  virtual void TurnOff() override { ... }
  virtual void SetVolume(int volume) override { ... }
}
```

And finally, your client code can use an instance of a TV (maybe created through a Factory) to drive the functionalities:

```
main()
{
  ...
  TelevisionInterface tv = ...
  tv.TurnOn();
  tv.SetVolume(100);
  ...
}
```

That seems like a perfect case for inheritance and polymorphism. Each specialized TV class handles hardware specific calls, which are encapsulated, and the client code can simply call methods it cares about.
All good right?

Let's see what happens when we introduce a new TV implementation. This time we have a smart TV, which adds a new functionality to support: launching YouTube. The new specialization is easy, but to support this new functionality, we have to amend TelevisionInterface. Other specializations do not support the functionality, so we can have a default [not supported] implementation in the interface.

```
// New and improved interface
class TelevisionInterface
{
public:
  virtual void TurnOn() = 0;
  virtual void TurnOff() = 0;
  virtual void SetVolume(int volume) = 0;
  virtual void LaunchYoutube() { } // Not supported unless overriden
}

// New smart TV to support
class TelevisionSony789 : public TelevisionInterface
{
public:
  virtual void TurnOn() override { ... }
  virtual void TurnOff() override { ... }
  virtual void SetVolume(int volume) override { ... }
  virtual void LaunchYoutube() override { ... }
}
```

You may see where I am going with this. As time goes on and new TVs are added, some differences in their specialization will accumulate, causing the interface to grow in size and responsibility.

**How best can we keep the code manageable when using an interface that supports too many functionalities?**

In the above case, a new layer of inheritance could have been added, called SmartTelevisionInterface (which inherits TelevisionInterface), but to me that only shifts the responsibility of differentiating a TV from a Smart TV to the client code.

Comment: Why not a new interface ? That's what Interface Segregation principle suggests too. Instead of adding it to the same interface, create a new interface with only the functionalities which are new. Then implement in the child class.

Comment: Swap your point of view. The clients of the interface defines what it needs to support, not its implementations. If its clients need all the different methods, it makes sense to add them. Otherwise, there's most likely a missing abstraction somewhere.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida And it becomes the client code's responsibility to handle TVs and Smart TVs differently?

Comment: @VincentSavard Makes sense. Let's assume that all implemented functionalities are functionalities that the client code needs. Does that mean that this is the best it gets?

Comment: @AlexMillette _"And it becomes the client code's responsibility to handle TVs and Smart TVs differently?"_ If the client intends to do "normal" (= non-smart) things with the TV, the client doesn't even need to know what kind of TV they're working with. But when the client intends to do smart things with the TV, obviously the client therefore requires a smart TV, not just any old TV.

Comment: @AlexMillette yes. For example, your current smart TV doesn't have a voice assistant. But a new smart TV might have. Then you will be creating another implementation. That is what you would do with segregation too. But you will have smaller interfaces with a specific detail. This supports your requirement to make the code manageable.

Comment: *Let's see what happens when we introduce a new TV implementation.* You're not just adding a new implementation; you're adding new feature functionality. It's unrealistic to expect to be able to do that without changing the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The new specialization is easy, but to support this new functionality, we have to amend TelevisionInterface.

This is where you are wrong. You don't have to amend `TelevisionInterface`, because **not all televisions can open Youtube**.

Instead, you should create a new interface, e.g. `SmartTelevisionInterface`, which derives from `TelevisionInterface` but adds some more things to it (in this case the `OpenYoutube()` method).

I'm not sure what language you were using. I'm sticking with C# but the syntax is very similar.

```
interface TelevisionInterface
{
    void TurnOn();
    void TurnOff();
    void SetVolume(int volume);
}

interface SmartTelevisionInterface : TelevisionInterface
{
    void OpenYoutube();
}
```

Now you can implement either interface as you choose:

```
class OldTelevision : TelevisionInterface
{
    // must implement:
    //    - TurnOn
    //    - TurnOff
    //    - SetVolume
}

class SmartTelevision : SmartTelevisionInterface
{
    // must implement:
    //    - TurnOn
    //    - TurnOff
    //    - SetVolume
    //    - OpenYoutube
}
```

When I say "must implement", I mean that the compiler forces you to provide an implementation for these methods, because otherwise it will refuse to compile your code.

This means that for "old" TV logic, you can use *either* regular or smart TVs, but for smart TV logic, you can enforce that you can only use smart TVs

```
public void FiddleWithTV(TelevisionInterface tv)
{
    tv.TurnOn();
    tv.SetVolume(55);
    tv.TurnOff();
}

public void FiddleWithSmartTV(SmartTelevisionInterface tv)
{
    tv.TurnOn();
    tv.OpenYoutube();
    tv.TurnOff();
}

FiddleWithTV(new OldTelevision());        // works
FiddleWithTV(new SmartTelevision());      // works
FiddleWithSmartTV(new OldTelevision());   // DOES NOT COMPILE - OldTelevision does not implement SmartTelevisionInterface
FiddleWithSmartTV(new SmartTelevision()); // works
```

---

Because you talked about "growing polymorphic interfaces", I think you should have a close look at the [Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle). It touches on the problem domain that you are faced with here.

---

I also noticed that in your code, you're not actually using interfaces, but rather classes with virtual implementations. While it somewhat gets the job done, it's not what you should be aiming for here, *provided your target language supports true interfaces*.

Even if not, you should consider abstract classes, rather than classes with virtual implementations. The difference being that abstract classes and interfaces can **force** an implementor to implement the specified members, whereas virtual methods make it optional, which is not what you want.

You wouldn't want me to create a `SpecialTelevision` which you can turn on but not turn off, right? Well, then you have to force me to implement the whole interface, not just leave it up to me to choose what parts I'd like to override.

Comment: Code samples were in C++. Interface is not a keyword in C++, but they are often closely reproduced by using a pure abstract class. A pure abstract class cannot be instantiated, just like an interface in C#. Virtual keyword allows for polymorphic overriding, but it is the "= 0;" label that makes it necessary to be overriden.

Comment: None of the above takes away from your answer. I'm not convinced that shifting responsibility to the client code is always better. Maybe the example of the smart TV implies that the client code should know about it, but we can imagine a regular old TV with a specific functionality that the others did not have. Should I take from that that there is a point at which the child classes are different enough to be split?

Comment: @AlexMillette Eventually you have a big mess of supported features with no particular structure to it (no implication of X -> Y) and so what you end up doing is `if(tv.CanOpenYoutube()) tv.OpenYoutube();` everywhere. I can think of at least 3 different ways to implement this pattern (interfaces, specific Can checks, generic Can checks), but if you have many orthogonal features, I can't really think of a different pattern.

Comment: I don’t know C++ but in c# you could say: if(television is SmartTelevisionInterface smartTv) smartTv.OpenYoutube();

Comment: @AlexMillette: I should've linked this earler, but have a look at the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle/), specifically this link's example for `BasicCoffeeMachine` and `PremiumCoffeeMachine`. The overall idea is that implementors **must** genuinely implement their members (whether via class inheritance or interface implementation). Intentional duds are to be avoided.

Comment: @Flater just out of curiosity, why is the interface inherited for the smart TV? We can use multiple interface as well right? Is it because, it has the same functionality as the old TV or any other reason?

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida: **(a)** If you had created the `SmartTelevisionInterface` on its own, with the same methods (and more) than `TelevisionInterface` but without inheriting, you could not have done `FiddleWithTV(new SmartTelevision())`. You'd be stuck with duplicating logic that applies for the two interface types. **(b)** By inheriting the interface, as opposed to implementing two interfaces on the same class, I am able to declare that _all_ smart TVs also are normal TVs. Now, it's impossible to have a `SmartTelevisionInterface` object whose volume cannot be set.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida: In other words, if there was a "smart object" who could only open Youtube but not have its volume changed; I should not have inherited the interfaces the way I did. But since it's a "smart **TV**", it seems logical that it therefore is an extension of what a TV already is, hence the inheritance.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida: Just to finish my thought: if we need to provide for normal TVs, youtube players (not a TV) _and_ smart TVs; you'd be inclined to have a `TelevisionInterface`, `YoutubePlayerInterface`, and then you can still inherit using `SmartTelevisionInterface : TelevisionInterface, YoutubePlayerInterface`. This way, both `FiddleWithTV(new SmartTelevision())` and `FiddleWithYoutubePlayer(new SmartTelevision())` would be valid as well, which promotes reusable logic.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with a dedicated `LaunchYoutube` method if this is important to a lot of your clients. This is no different from the dedicated Netflix button on the Roku remote: a lot of people watch Netflix and a dedicated button is the quickest way to get to the app.

Continuing with the Roku analogy, most of their remotes have 4 dedicated app buttons, but of course there's also the general navigation buttons so that you can browse and open any app that's not directly on the remote. As Alan Kay said, "simple things should be simple, complex things should be possible".

So depending on the number and importance of features/apps you need to support, you might settle for a handful of `LaunchSpecificApp()` methods, a generic `Launch(appName)` method or a combination of the two. If you go for a hybrid approach, only `Launch(appName)` would likely be an abstract method and the "quick access" methods can just delegate to it.